# WinAppDriver: Right click on a tab.(C#)

Tags: c#, winappdriver

There are few tabs in my application (Desktop Application). Able to identify the tab and Select it successfully.
Looking for optimal way to right click on tab, so that I can have access to context menu options.

NOTE: Shift+F10 is not working.

Comment: Show us your tries, and an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the Action class

Actions CtRightClick = new Actions(session);

CtRightClick.ContextClick().Perform();